# Outline TextView

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли сделать такую обводку `TextView`? Если да, то с чего начать?

**Пример:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 100% такую будет сложно, но похожую - при помощи обычной тени

Comment: @metalurgus эх, просто тень сильно размывается и контраст неявный в итоге:(

Comment: Можете попробовать рисовать текст дважды на канве с уменьшением размера и смещением во второй раз

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотрите [статью на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150871/) или библиотеку [MagicTextView](https://github.com/m5/MagicTextView).

Либо поиграться с [тенями](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на хабр, помогло:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад что помог :)

Answer (score 8):

Просмотрев статью на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150871/), я переделал его для `TextView`.

**OutlineTextView.java:**

```
package com.example.outlinetextview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Join;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.outlinetextview.R;

public class OutlineTextView extends TextView {
    private int strokeColor= Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private int strokeWidth=2;

    public OutlineTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public OutlineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OutlineTextView);
        strokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.OutlineTextView_textStrokeColor, strokeColor);
        strokeWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.OutlineTextView_textStrokeWidth, strokeWidth);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final ColorStateList textColor = getTextColors();
        TextPaint paint = this.getPaint();
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeMiter(10);
        this.setTextColor(strokeColor);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        setTextColor(textColor);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**attrs:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ....
    <declare-styleable name="OutlineTextView">
        <attr name="textStrokeColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="textStrokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    ....
</resources>
```

**example.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.outlinetextview.OutlineTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        app:textStrokeWidth="5sp"
        app:textStrokeColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. Надеюсь кому-нить пригодится:)*